# Bootstrap pop over is not closing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using the bootstrap pop over when click one certain button it gots opened and closed with same button click again.

I tried to add a close button beside of title and it has done but when I clicked on close button is not closing.

My code:

```
$('#emailPopover').popover({
        placement:'right',
        trigger: 'click',
        html: true,
        title:'Voter Variables'+
             '<button type="button" id="close" class="close" onclick="$(this).popover("hide");">&times;</button>'
    });
```

Comment: What's value of `$(this)` in `onclick`? For sure not `$("#emailPopover")`, just drop JavaScript in favor of `data-` attributes.

Comment: It also not working tried with $("#emailPopover").popover('hide') .

Comment: you're nesting quotes little bit too freely...use `&quot;` as suggested by ChaoticNadirs (and `#emailPopover` instead of `this`).

Comment: This is wat I done but its not working 

 $('#emailPopover').popover({
  placement:'right',
  trigger: 'click',
  html: true,
   title:'Voter Variables'+
             '<button type="button" id="close" class="close" onclick="$(&quot;#emailPopover&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);">&times;</button>'
 });

Answer (score 2):

Try using `&quot;` instead of quotation marks like this:

```
$('#emailPopover').popover({
        placement:'right',
        trigger: 'click',
        html: true,
        title:'Voter Variables'+
             '<button type="button" id="close" class="close" onclick="$(&quot;#emailPopover&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);">&times;</button>'
    });
```

bootply example: http://www.bootply.com/pd2qZayqju

Comment: If I used like this popup is not at all opening

Comment: Is there any problemw with bootstrap version?

Comment: Please have a look at this

'<button type="button" class="close close_help" onclick="$(&quot;#emailPopover&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);">&times;</button>'

Comment: @Dura Which version you are used ?

Comment: I've copied the line you posted in your comment above into the demo and it works fine. You can check which version Bootply is using by clicking on the settings tab on the left. Have a look at [this doc](http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide)

Comment: I have used the same but its not working what may be the problem?

Comment: @sridhar anything in browser console or by inspection of generated popover html code?

Comment: onclick event for close button is triggering two times here. what could be the cause ?

Answer (score -1):

If your intent is to have the popover show when the user clicks on the button, and hide when the user clicks anywhere else, try the `trigger: 'focus'` option. [Check out the Bootstrap example Dismiss on next click for more details.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-examples)

Make sure you add `tabindex="0"` to the button in HTML

HTML:

```
<a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="emailPopover">Email</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#emailPopover').popover({
    placement:'right',
    trigger: 'focus',
    html: true,
    title:'Voter Variables'
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jcppk5o/)

Comment: $('#emailPopover').popover({
        placement:'right',
        trigger: 'click',
        html: true,
        title:'Voter Variables <button type="button" id="close" class="close" onclick="$("#emailPopover").popover("hide");">&times;</button>'
    }); 


HTML :

<a id="emailPopover" data-content="${variableSubstitutionList}">
                <span class="icon-question-sign">
                </span>
               </a>

Comment: If I used focus the pop up is not opening itself

Comment: sridhar, make sure you add the tabindex="0" to the button.